# Upgrade script when you don't know which version they have

Tags: upgrade, magento-ce

I know how to do upgrade scripts within Magento but the current way relies on me knowing the version the user is running.

If I have some users running v0.2 and some 0.3 but I want to make a change for anyone who moves onto 0.5 how I would I go about that?

I currently have:

```
mysql4-install-0.2.0.php
```

My new version will be `0.5.0` but some users are running `0.4.6` and some are running `0.4.9`.

Do I have to create an upgrade script for each of the versions users might be using? i.e

```
mysql4-upgrade-0.4.6-0.5.0.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.4.9-0.5.0.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to create the 0.4.9 - 0.5.0 script. Magento will automatically pickup the skip in version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a few upgrade-scripts. like:

```
upgrade-0.2.0-0.5.0.php
upgrade-0.3.0-0.5.0.php
```

and put different thing in them, depending what happend in version 0.3.0

Comment: I tried doing 0.2.0 to 0.5.0 but it didn't apply. I assume this is because I wasn't running version 0.2.0

Comment: Yes, it only applies if your version is before this. If you have Version 0.2.1 then 0.3.0 should run